# How can I search part of a field efficiently with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

I have a field which is an ID number for each document of a certain type. Let's say the user searches for '123'. I want this to be able to match with a document whose number is '123456'. I know I can use the [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) to achieve this but the documentation says that it's not the most efficient, especially since I want users to also be able to search for '456' and still find the '123456' document.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595060/how-do-i-configure-elasticsearch-to-find-substrings-at-the-beginning-or-at-the-e/33595238#33595238

Comment: Well I don't really mind it matching in the middle either, but that answer would be acceptable if there's no alternative.

Comment: You can definitely amend the answer to match in the middle, too.

Comment: I will try to implement the solution in that answer, thanks.